# How to download directly to ~/.drush folder?

Tags: drush

I've created a [project](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit) that is basically a drush command with a starterkit folder. I noticed the make_local project will but I haven't figured out how it does that.

I've tried the approach recommended in the answers and added a .info file and tried to hide the .profile extension by renaming it to .profile.starterkit.  Drush still thinks I'm downloading a theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three requirements:

1. Your project must have a .info file
2. Your project must have a project.drush.inc file
3. Your project must not have a project.module file or any sort of .profile file

If all three of these are true, then Drush will store the project in ~/.drush. If there is a module file or a .profile, then Drush will treat the project like a module or installation profile (usually storing it in sites/all/modules).

Your project was missing a .info file, but unfortunately, the existence of the profile file caused Drush to decide that your project was an installation profile, and Drush thinks that those do not belong in ~/.drush.

The user will have to specify --destination=$HOME/.drush, or move your project to the correct folder manually.

Comment: I've added the .info file but that hasn't seemed to help.  Here's what I see.
`drush dl panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit
Project panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit (7.x-1.x-dev) downloaded to /home/drupalpro/projects/panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit-7.x-1.x-dev.                            [success]
Project panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit contains:                                                                                                                           [success]
 - 1 profile: STARTERKIT
 - 1 theme: panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit`

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incomplete; I enhanced it. Previously, Drush did not think your project was a module (no .info file); now that there is an .info file, Drush thinks that your project is an installation profile.

Comment: thanks! that is helpful. the .profile file is a starterkit file so I can always alter the extension and change when executing the drush command.

Comment: i'm getting closer.  Drush no longer thinks I'm downloading a profile but still thinks I'm downloading a theme.

Comment: Drush is determining this by the info that drupal.org is putting together for you.  See: http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/panopoly_base_distribution_starter_kit/7.x

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not appear that you can give d.o a "hint" (e.g. type = module), as this is not supported in .info files. https://www.drupal.org/node/542202