# Drush stoped working and drush status -v shows Executing: vagrant

Tags: drush, virtual-machine

It's important to say that *I don't use vagrant!*

For some reason this afternoon drush stoped working, it remains stuck. If I run `drush status -v` I can see it get stuck at `Executing: vagrant`.
I may have typed something wrong at some point, maybe installed vagrant instead of varnish module but I can't remember and now I can't use drush anymore.

Does anyone have a clue on how to stop drush from trying to execute vagrant silently?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realize that I in the `~/.drush/` folder there is a `drush-vagrant` folder, after deleting it everything started working again.
The folder is from the drush-vagrant [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_vagrant) that I installed by mistake.
See drush folder download answer: [How to download directly to ~/.drush folder?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123095/how-to-download-directly-to-drush-folder)